Can't find element by any attribute
Explanation
I have a link that I want to click but this link is hidden under a hidden hamburger menu. I tried clicking the link by itself but it didn't work. So I tried to open the hamburger menu first and then searching for the element but it appears so that even the hamburger menu button couldn't be found.

HTML
<nav id="ember4" class="left-menu set-aria-hidden ember-view"><div class="FlexWrapper">
<div>
  <button aria-label="main navigation menu" class="menu-icon " type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-5="5">
    <span class="icon-menu_hamburger"></span>
    <span class="menu-text ">MENU</span>
  </button>
</div>
...
</nav>

Code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://connect.mheducation.com/connect/hmStudentCourseList.do?showSniffer=true&fromPage=login")

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-email')))
except TimeoutException as ex:
    print(ex)

driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-email").send_keys("CREDENTIALS")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-password").send_keys("CREDENTIALS")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-submit-btn").click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="list_2747337_item_15168696_text"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a')))
except TimeoutException as ex:
    print(ex)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="list_2747337_item_15168696_text"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a').click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember4"]/div/div[1]/button')))
except TimeoutException as ex:
    print(ex)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember4"]/div/div[1]/button').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ToDoMenu"]/a').click()

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Onur\Documents\HomeworkSolver\homeworkSolver.py", line 36, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="list_2747337_item_15168696_text"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a').click()
  File "C:\Users\Onur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Onur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Onur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Onur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such execution context
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.106)

From the error code, It seems like its having problems with finding an element prior to the actual element I've been trying to click yet it still clicks the element that has the XPATH
'//*[@id="list_2747337_item_15168696_text"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a'
and moves on the last page that the picture shows.
What is the problem here? If it can't find the element how can it click it? Is this the actual reason I can't find the navbar button I'm trying to click?
Notes
Python 3.12.2
Selenium 4.19.0

Give it a try without options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

Have your tired using the full xpath of the element after you make it visible and inspect it in chrome? This tends to work for me. Let me know if this helps.
